# Create a virtualenv to run jupyter

Tags: python

I have created a new virtualenv and named it python with command `virtualenv python`.

output:

```
Using base prefix '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7'
New python executable in /Users/dema/python/bin/python3.7
Also creating executable in /Users/dema/python/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...
done.
```

Then I activate it with commande `source python/bin/activate`

Then I installed jupyter notebook with commande `pip3 install notebook`

Then I try running the notebook with command `jupyter notebook`

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda2/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 7, in <module>
    from notebook.notebookapp import main
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 60, in <module>
    from tornado import httpserver
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/httpserver.py", line 33, in <module>
    from tornado.http1connection import HTTP1ServerConnection, HTTP1ConnectionParameters
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/http1connection.py", line 30, in <module>
    from tornado import iostream
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/iostream.py", line 40, in <module>
    from tornado.netutil import ssl_wrap_socket, _client_ssl_defaults, _server_ssl_defaults
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/netutil.py", line 44, in <module>
    _client_ssl_defaults = ssl.create_default_context(
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'create_default_context'
```

Why do Anaconda and python2.7 come into this when I am using an active env with python3.7? I am totally unable to understand.

Comment: You have a PATH conflict. Check your shell profile scripts. You can also try using `python3 -m jupyter notebook`.

Comment: Why do you use both, `virtualenv` and `conda`?